# How do I use C# to convert int to bytes that only use the low 4 bits?

Tags: c#

I have a conversion problem in C#. Basically, I'm trying to convert an integer to bytes so that we only use the low 4 bits. Example `255 = 0F 0F` or:

```
0xpqrs = 0p 0q 0r 0s

5*16*16*16 + 1*16*16 + 15*16 + 1  = 05 01 0f 01
```

How do I implement this in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int => bytes:

```
int value = 0x51f1;
byte s = (byte)(value & 0xf);
byte r = (byte)(value>>4 & 0xf);
byte q = (byte)(value>>8 & 0xf);
byte p = (byte)(value>>12 & 0xf);
```

bytes => int:

```
int value = p<<12 | q<<8 | r<<4 | s;
```

Comment: Apologies for before - I think I'd misunderstood the question.

Comment: No prob! There was a problem however, + taking precedence over the << operator.

Comment: @Lucero: Can you please explain more your answer? I don't understand `value & 0xf` and `value>>4 & 0xf`, ... . Why you `AND`  with `0xf`? Thanks

Comment: @Arian First lets be clear that this is a bitwise AND, not a logical AND. The 0xf is equivalent to `0b1111` (e.g. the lowest 4 bits are 1, all the others 0). Therefore I take the value, shift it by 0/4/8/12 bits to the right, and then filter it so that only the lowest 4 bits remain, thus getting a value between 0x0..0xf (both inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

Lucero's answer modified to work in a loop with longer integers.

```
    public static byte[] intToBytesV2(ulong l)
    {
        byte[] theBytes = new byte[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            theBytes[i] = (byte)(l >> (i * 4) & 0xf);
        }
        return theBytes;
    }
```

pom =)

Answer (score -1):

byte[] bArray=System.BitConverter.GetBytes(i);

Comment: That will get the bytes, but not do the masking.